# AWS: cannot access DynamoDB from EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have and nodejs application which is running on EC2 instance. Whenever the application requests DynamoDB (via aws-sdk) i get this response:

`<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'elasticbeanstalk'. </Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>`

The EC2 instance is created with default profile. And i tried to attach policies to the profile granting full access to DynamoDB and IAM. No luck.

I found this article on aws-docs
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

And seems there is described exactly the issue i am experiencing. But i still do not get how to fix it.

Regarding credentials, i rely on aws-sdk which is requesting temporary credentials and i dont use any local config for credentials.

There is something strange in the response that results in the error i mentioned. It`s authorization header look like:
`Credential=SOME_KEY_HERE/20150703/us-west-2/dynamodb/aws4_request`

but the host is:
`host: 'elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'`

May be it is the cause of the problem?

I am new to AWS, and i will really appreciate any help! I read docs about IAM Roles, but still have no luck with the issue. =(

Comment: It sounds as if your request for dynamodb is actually being sent to an Elastic Beanstalk API endpoint, instead of to dynamodb.  Maybe show your code where you're setting up objects and making the dynamodb request?